# How to access HttpContext from IRequestHandler using Mediator - Minimal API (C#)

Tags: c#, mediator, minimal-apis

Is there a way to access HttpContext from a request handler?
I added a filter to my (minimal API) endpoint to validate the API key, coming from the request headers. Upon successful validation I need the value to Generate JWT for subsequent requests.

Is there a workaround to this? Need a code sample.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can add a middleware to catch the token, store it in some scoped service and retrieve on filter by dependency injection.

Comment: You can also take a look into [Carter](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter). It has an IEndpointFilter that contains HttpContext.

Comment: Can you please share some code? What exactly is `IRequestHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Carter](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter), it would be something like this (but it is just matter of using equivalent for non-Carter implementation):

```
public interface ITokenGrabber
{
    void SetToken(string token);
    string GetToken();
}

public class TokenGrabber : ITokenGrabber
{
    private string _token;

    public string GetToken() => _token;

    public void SetToken(string token) => _token = token;
}

public class SampleFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    public ValueTask<object> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        var grabber = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITokenGrabber>();

        string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            
        grabber.SetToken(token);

        return next(context);
    }
}

    public class SomeHandler
        : IRequestHandler<SomeRequest>
    {
        private readonly ITokenGrabber _grabber;

        public GetAllExercisesQueryHandle(ITokenGrabber grabber)
        {
            _grabber = grabber;
        }

        public Task Handle(SomeRequestrequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_grabber.GetToken());
            
            return ...
        }
    }
```

Make sure `ITokenGrabber` is properly configured with `scoped` lifetime:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenGrabber, TokenGrabber>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use HttpContextAccessor, which allows custom components to access the HttpContext via dependency injection. Your `IRequestHandler` can then inject `IHttpContextAccessor`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components

> For other framework and custom components that require access to
> HttpContext, the recommended approach is to register a dependency
> using the built-in Dependency Injection (DI) container. The DI
> container supplies the `IHttpContextAccessor` to any classes that
> declare it as a dependency in their constructors:
>
> `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

Be sure to consider the lifetime of your `IRequestHandler` if you're using scoped information such as the HttpContext user, and consider applying the requisite data from the user into the request DTO itself rather than having the handler take a dependency on an ambient scoped piece of information, as that reduces some of the value of abstracting the handlers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks also for your support. Thanks a million.